# Define custom POST method for MyDAC

Tags: mysql, delphi, mydac

I have three tables `objects`, (primary key `object_ID`) `flags` (primary key `flag_ID`) and `object_flags` (cross-tabel between `objects` and `flags` with some extra info).

I have a query returning all flags, and a one or zero if a given object has a certain flag:

```
SELECT
  f.*,
  of.*,
  of.objectID IS NOT NULL AS object_has_flag,
FROM
  flags f
  LEFT JOIN object_flags of
    ON (f.flag_ID = of.flag_ID) AND (of.object_ID = :objectID);
```

In the application (which is written in Delphi), all rows are loaded in a component. The user can assign flags by clicking check boxes in a table, modifying the data.

Suppose one line is edited. Depending on the value of object_has_flag, the following things have to be done:

- If object_has_flag was true and still is true, an UPDATE should be done on the relevant row in objects_flags.
- If object_has_flag was false but is now true, and INSERT should be done
- If object_has_flag was true, but is now false, the row should be deleted

It seems that this cannot be done in one query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927114/conditional-replace-or-delete-in-one-query.

I'm using MyDAC's TMyQuery as a dataset. I have written separate code that executes the necessary queries to save changes to a row, but how do I couple this to the dataset? What event handler should I use, and how do I tell the TMyQuery that it should refresh instead of post?

EDIT: apparently, it is not completely clear what the problem is. The standard UpdateSQL, DeleteSQL and InsertSQL cannot be used because sometimes after *editing* a line (not deleting it or inserting a line), an `INSERT` or `DELETE` has to be done.

Comment: In your former question, you didn't mention wether the off-the-shelf components you were using was MyDAC. Was that so?

Comment: @menjaraz (sorry for the delay): it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the easiest way is to use the `BeforePost` event, and determine what has to be done using the `OldValue` and `NewValue` properties of several fields.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, to paraphrase your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5563478/744588):

- Look up the documentation for "Updating Data with MyDAC Dataset Components" (as of MyDAC 5.80).

Every **TCustomDADataSet** (such as TMyQuery) descendant has the capability to set update SQL statements using *SQLInsert*, *SQLUpdate* and *SQLDelete* properties.

**TMyUpdateSQL** is also a promising component for custom update operations.

Comment: True. However, some built-in sanity checks will cause trouble. For instance, when using REPLACE in case a record already exists, the server will return 2 rows affected. A built-in sanity check will raise an exception because only one row was edited.